# How to automatically enable custom worker dynos on Heroku specified in Procfile and app.json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, procfile, heroku-review-app

I'm attempting to deploy our app using heroku review apps but we can't seem to enable the worker dynos automatically. It seems like the `formation` designations are being completely ignored. When I run `curl -n https://api.heroku.com/apps/{APP_NAME}/formation \ -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"` it returns the right number of processes, right process names, but with size `hobby` and quantity `0` instead of the sizes/quantities specified in `app.json`.

This is roughly what our `Procfile` and `app.json` configurations look like:

**Procfile:**

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker-one: bundle exec sidekiq -c 1 -q something
worker-two: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -q something-else
release: bin/heroku_release_phase
```

**app.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Flowspace",
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/Lostmyname/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean"
    }
  ],
  "formation": {
    "web": {
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": "hobby"
    },
    "worker-one": {
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": "standard-1x"
    },
    "worker-two": {
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": "standard-1x"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: The only hunch I have so far is that maybe the `app.json` can only reference workers defined in the original `Procfile` and not in the custom Procfile referenced here that is used via heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile buildpack.